# Gitolite authentication using ldap over web on https

Tags: ldap, gitolite

I want to setup my gitolite server in web using ldap credentials and perform all git features .Currently I am able to host my server in web but only as a normal user , now I want to login through ldap credentials .

my requirement is to use only https/http , no ssh or any keys .

Please let me know if anyone has the answer or any documents for it .It would be really helpful.

I am able to host my server in web but only for normal user , now I want to login through ldap credentials .

I tried googling it , got a lot of stuff tried it but didn't get any results .

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but you can try and check out [`tillsteinbach/gitolite-ldap-config`](https://github.com/tillsteinbach/gitolite-ldap-config).

It redirects ssh calls to [`ldap_authorized_keys.sh`](https://github.com/tillsteinbach/gitolite-ldap-config/blob/master/ldap_authorized_keys.sh), which then perform a `$LDAPSEARCH -x -o ldif-wrap=no -LLL '(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(sshPublicKey=*))' sshPublicKey`

Comment: Thankyou for this . However i actually need ldap authentication for gitolite only using https or http (no ssh keys to be used) in this authentication. Please let me know if there is any such way .

Comment: @anonymous The same project proposes an [HTTPS wrapper](https://github.com/tillsteinbach/gitolite-ldap-config/blob/master/gitolite_http_wrapper_script.sh) which will redirect to LDAP

Comment: I have tried using what you have suggested from the article as per my understanding but no luck solving here too . Please let me know if there is anything in details as this is something which is a bit new for me .